# Linking OpenCV library

Tags: opencv

So i already install OpenCV library two years ago on virtualenviroment for python and it work well using [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/) step. Now i create some image processing program in C languange, but everytime i try to compile, it always couldn't find the OpenCV library.

```
Package checking always able to detect OpenCV
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.1.0
```

But if i run my make file

Below my make file, `linux.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
#     base=`basename $1`
#     echo "compiling $base"
#     g++ -ggdb `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` $1 -o $base 
# if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
#   base=`basename $1 .c`
#   echo "compiling $base"
#   gcc -ggdb `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` $base.c -o $base 
if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    base=`basename $1 .cpp`
    echo "compiling $base"
    g++ -ggdb `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` $base.cpp -o $base 
else
    for i in *.c; do
        echo "compiling $i"
        gcc -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $i .c` $i `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lm;
    done
    for i in *.cpp; do
        echo "compiling $i"
        g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $i .cpp` $i `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lm;
    done
fi
```

It always return this

```
compiling main.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_aruco
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_bgsegm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_bioinspired
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ccalib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dnn
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dpm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_fuzzy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_line_descriptor
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_optflow
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_plot
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_reg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_saliency
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_stereo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_structured_light
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_rgbd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_surface_matching
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_tracking
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_datasets
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_text
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_face
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xfeatures2d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_shape
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ximgproc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xobjdetect
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xphoto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_videoio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I search where my OpenCV library located, and i found it in /usr/local/lib : It contain everything that needed such as libopencv_aruco.so.3.1, libopencv_bgsegm.so.3.1 and etc.

I have try several solution online but it still not working. So, how could i solve this problem **without ruining my entire system** that still working fine?

**Update #1**
Result from pkg-config --libs opencv

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lippicv -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

I try one solution from again [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67781/use-shared-libraries-in-usr-local-lib) :

Step i did :

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/Robotika.conf
```

And in that, i type this

```
/usr/local/lib
```

After that

```
sudo ldconfig
```

OK BASED on comment, this solution is not for my case

**Update #2**
When i run

```
$ namei -l /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so
f: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root local
drwxr-xr-x root root lib
                     libopencv_aruco.so - No such file or directory
```

library not detected, but if i run :

```
$ namei -l /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.3.1
f: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.3.1
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root local
drwxr-xr-x root root lib
lrwxrwxrwx root root libopencv_aruco.so.3.1 -> libopencv_aruco.so.3.1.0
-rw-r--r-- root root   libopencv_aruco.so.3.1.0
```

it detected.

Comment: So, what is the output of `pkg-config --libs opencv`?

Comment: @steeldriver, i just add output of that command and i try another solution but still not work, maybe I do that step wrong?

Comment: `ldconfig` only affects the loading of libraries at runtime afaik - it won't help here. Please check that the OpenCV `.so` files in /usr/local/lib are **readable** by the invoking user ex. `namei -l /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so`

Comment: @steeldriver, ok i have check what you suggest, above my system output in Update #2

Comment: OK thanks - so it looks like the libraries are there but (at least some of) the symbolic links are missing (there should be a symlink from `libopencv_aruco.so -> libopencv_aruco.so.3.1` for example)

Comment: @steeldriver how could i do that? since thats a lot of file, can i one file that link every library.

Comment: You could try something like `for f in /usr/local/lib/libopencv*.so.3.1; do echo ln -s "${f##*/}" "${f%.3.1*}"; done` - if the output looks sensible, replace `echo` with `sudo` to actually create the links. So long as you **don't** add the `-f` flag, the `ln` command should not overwrite any existing links.

Comment: @steeldriver ok it work great after i use sudo instead of echo! Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Could u put your answer in answer section :)